# Switching tabs in tabbar controller

Tags: iphone

I am working on app, in which I have 2 switch between tabs in tabbar controller. Is it possible in iphone. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: please make your question more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called "selectedIndex".

If you wanted to switch to your second TabBar, you'd call

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Your tabbars start from index 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use **selectedIndex** property . it can help you.